# Gathering data from multi page form, and adding additional data

Tags: laravel, forms, laravel-5

So I'm data from a multi-page form, the data is stored like this.

I'm using this tutorial https://www.5balloons.info/multi-page-step-form-in-laravel-with-validation/

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $user = $request->session()->get('user');
    $user->save();
    return redirect('/home');
}
```

That works fine. But how do I add additional data manually using the arrow function? For example, I need to set a status, the ip address, ect. Something like 'status' => 1

Comment: You mean you want to do some stuff like `$user->status = 1; $user->ip_address = '127.0.0.1';`?

Comment: Yes, manually set the data, in addition to data supplied by the user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is the only place you want to add these values to users, you could just add the values after you got it from the session:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $user = $request->session()->get('user');
    $user->ip_address = '127.0.0.1';
    $user->status = 1;
    $user->save();
    return redirect('/home');
}
```

Comment: That's just what I need. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

you can add addition data like:

if your $user is laravel object then

```
$user->setAttribute('status', '1');
```

or $user if array then

```
$user['status']=1;
```